# Replace an element in an array at a specified index

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var left=[323,345,654,123];
```

How can I replace `345`? I have tried :

```
left[2]=456
```

But it didn't work.

(I can use jQuery if that's relevant.)

Comment: Indexes are zero-based. `left[1] = 456`

Comment: I recommend working through some basic JavaScript tutorials and books.

Answer (score 4):

The index in an array (*in nearly every programming language*) starts with zero! So if you want to replace the second value of an array, you need the index of `1`.

```
// index:    0    1    2    3
var left = [323, 345, 654, 123];
left[1] = 456;
```

For further example, the array is now accessible like:

```
left[0]; // 323
left[1]; // 456
left[2]; // 654
left[3]; // 123
```

And you don't need jQuery at all for this. It is is plain, basic javascript.